# What does わ in this sentence meant?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation

> そうね、じゃ、これかこれね。このポケットは大きいから、たくさん入るわね。

Does これかこれね mean is it this or is it the other?

From my understanding the whole sentence meant something like - Because it has big pocket so I can put a lot of things inside. Correct me if I am wrong and thank you in advance

Comment: What are you asking, exactly?  Are you asking about わ, or これかこれね?

Comment: Oops sorry two questions actually. The わ in 入れるわね as well as これかこれね

Comment: Possible duplicate (regarding わね): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/52205/9831

Answer (score 2):

> Does これかこれね mean is it this or is it the other?

Yes. `か` means `or` in this case.

アップルかバナナを食べよう → Let's eat apple or banana.

> 入れるわね

I don't know how to explain this `わ`. This is emphasis, emotion. Something like `YEP, really a lot will go in`.

For example

この家を自分で建てた → I built this house by myself
おおお、自分でできた？ やるわ！ → Wow, can you did it by yourself? You did it (you are cool, you are artisan)!

Maybe [this](https://context.reverso.net/%E7%BF%BB%E8%A8%B3/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E-%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E/%E3%82%8F) helps.

Answer (score -4):

First, there is a mistake in the sentence. It should read:

... たくさん入る**は**ね。

If the sentence had been just ... たくさん入る。 then the translation would be "It has lots of pockets so a lot will go in." However the person is expressing some ambivalence in the way they are speaking. The first sentence is very hesitant: "Yes, well, it's this or that, isn't it." The same hesitancy is expressed in the second sentence by adding "はね". A better translation that gives this sense of hesitancy in English would be:

"I guess a lot will go in because it has so many pockets."

Comment: there is no mistake. This わ is not は like in これは入る. https://context.reverso.net/翻訳/日本語-英語/やるわよ